# Concate two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe and try to join them but failed, can you please help me.

dataframe 1

```
      0
0     0
1  -100

...

20  400
21  500
```

dataframe 2

```
               Rate
Date               
2015-04-01      NaN
2015-04-02 -0.00346
2015-04-03  0.00323

...

2015-04-29  0.00296
2015-04-30  0.00878
```

I want to join them to be:

```
Rate          0
Date               
2015-04-01      NaN      0
2015-04-02 -0.00346   -100
2015-04-03  0.00323      0

...

2015-04-29  0.00296    400
2015-04-30  0.00878    500
```

but using this

```
concate = pd.concat([dataframe1, dataframe2], axis=1, join_axes=[dataframe1.index])
print gabung
```

I got this:

```
               Rate   0
Date                   
2015-04-01      NaN NaN
2015-04-02 -0.00346 NaN
2015-04-03  0.00323 NaN

...

2015-04-29  0.00296 NaN
2015-04-30  0.00878 NaN
```

How to fix the code so get me the result I want. Thank you

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is because its trying to align on index but the index values don't match so it's better to just add the column as anonymous np array values like JoeCondron has answered

Answer (score 0):

you could just do

```
dataframe2['values'] = dataframe1[0].values
```

So just insert a column to the second data frame, since this is the one you want to keep the index of. I just chose `'values'` as an arbitrary name for the column in the result but you can put anything you lie there.

Answer (score 0):

Concatination denotes two lists being put after each other, like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"data":[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"data":[4,5,6]})
pd.concat([df1, df2])
    data
0   1
1   2
2   3
0   4
1   5
2   6
```

Merging (Joining) would need a key to join on.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"data1":[1,2,3], "key":["John", "Janice", "Jake"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"data2":[4,5,6], "key":["John", "Janice", "Jake"]})
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on="key")
    data1   key     data2
0   1   John    4
1   2   Janice  5
2   3   Jake    6
```

Adding a new column to an existing dataframe is simple assignment:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"data":[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"data":[4,5,6]})
df1['data2'] = df2['data']
    data    data2
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

Comment: Thank you :) You are so nice.

Comment: @saturnmoon No problem, and once you get 15 points, don't forget to upvote the answer that you found the most useful.